# In AngularJs is possible to set a ng-controller through a variable name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, controller, ng-controller

Simple question, this is my scenario:

```
<div ng-repeat="slide in sliders" onfinishrender id="slide-page-{{slide.id}}" class="slidepage" data-page-type="{{slide.type}}">
    <div ng-controller="slide.type + 'Ctrl'" class="inner-container" ng-include src="'templates/content/' + slide.type + '.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to set a controller into a div setting its name according to a dynamic variable? I tried some solution, but nothing worked.
Thanks in advance

Comment: that doesn't exactly make sense, as you should already be inside a controller for the `ng-repeat` to work, and nesting controllers isn't really a best practice.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: if you *really* have to nest controllers like this, using `ng-controller="{{slide.type}}Ctrl"` should work, though;

Comment: are you try to create controller for every div?

Comment: I need to load content for every slide, every time a different event happen. Every slide has its own different content, then what I would like to achieve is to have my appropriate (and different) controller to behave differently for every slide

Comment: this is logic that would make a lot more sense as a directive

Comment: Changing your ng-controller value with what Claies said can work. But you would need to instantiate the controller inside your javascript too. Seems it would be better inside a directive

Comment: Should I really need a directive for a whole template? I mean, one different directive for every slide?

Comment: You can create a single directive and reuse it, but that will depend on your implementation. Directives can be parameterised in a number of ways, therefore you should be able to produce a single template and configure it per value in the repeat statement. Brief guide on directives: http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Comment: directives don't have to be heavy, they can be lightweight;  in practice, creating re-usable HTML like elements is exactly the problem that directives were created to solve